# How to create a VPC endpoint to access SQL DB hosted inside EC2 instance?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I have a lambda in VPC-1 trying to access a SQL database which is hosted inside an EC2 instance in VPC-2.
How should I establish a connection between Lambda(VPC-1) and SQL DB (VPC-2) using VPC endpoint?
What configuration I need to do in infrastructure and code?

I don't want to do VPC peering as it is not allowed in my organization.

Comment: Hello. Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the Lambda function is connected to a different VPC (VPC-1)? Is it because it _also_ needs to connect to something in VPC-1? If not, you could simply change the Lambda function to connect to VPC-2.

Comment: Yes. Lambda needs to be in VPC-1. I cannot change its VPC.